# why keyboard can not push up the view of a Fragment that lives inside the ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollview, android-softkeyboard

i have a fragment inside the viewpager that has a editText on it.when i open the keyboard,it can not push up the layout for scrolling.when i open my keyboard i cant access rest of the view because view cant scroll itself.i tried all type of softInputs in my manifest and in my activity .but it does not work.